# iOS Facebook ShareLink Handling Interfering with Facebook Login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I have 3 issues, all of them revolving around link sharing with the Facebook API. Here is the code I'm using to share links:

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "fb.me app link url")!
content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "image url")         
let messageDialog: FBSDKMessageDialog = FBSDKMessageDialog()
messageDialog.delegate = self
messageDialog.shareContent = content 
if messageDialog.canShow() {
    messageDialog.show()
}
```

I have this function in my AppDelegate.swift to handle incoming shared links:

```
func application(app: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    handleSharedLink(url: url)
    return true
}
```

Here are the 3 issues:

1. I also have Facebook Login in my app and the openURL function in my AppDelegate is interfering with it. It gets called during Facebook login and even if I remove the handleSharedLink() function call and just return true, it'll cause the Facebook login to stop halfway. How can I handle this properly so that my shared link handling doesn't interfere with Facebook login?
2. When I send a link using FBSDKShareLinkContent (with the code above), and I tap on it in Facebook messenger on a phone that has my app installed, it opens the app and works fine. However, when I try opening it on a phone that doesn't have my app installed, it does nothing. According to the Facebook API documentation, it should redirect the user to the app store if the user doesn't have the app installed, if I'm not mistaken. How can I achieve this functionality?
3. I used Facebook to make an App Link for my app that begins with fb.me. When I share the link using FBSDKShareLinkContent (code above), then it displays the fb.me link to the person I have shared with. How do I make it so it doesn't show?

Any help on the above 3 issues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer myself after quite a bit of experimentation and rereading the docs. For anyone having similar issues, you can solve all of the issues described in the question with the following 2 steps.

1. Add this function to your AppDelegate:

   ```swift
   func application(app: UIApplication,
                    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
       //Check if the url has app link data
       let checkUrl = BFURL(inboundURL: url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String)

       if checkUrl != nil {
           //Handle incoming shared link
       } else {
           //Take care of handling url for Facebook login
           return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
               app,
               openURL: url,
               sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String,
               annotation: nil)
       }
   }
   ```
2. In code for FBSDKShareLinkContent, instead of setting the contentURL to a fb.me url you created, set it to the url of your app's website. In your app website's header, add the following meta tags.

   ```html
   <meta property="al:ios:url" content="app url configured in info.plist"/>

   <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="itunes app store id" />

   <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="name of your app" />
   ```